# Merging data frame columns into a vector

Tags: r, vector

I am wondering if there are prettier ways to produce the following result without using string splitting :

```
library('magrittr')
combn(5, 2) %>% 
  t %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  mutate(
      string = paste(V1, V2, sep = ';')
    , vector = string %>% strsplit(split = ';')
    ) %>% View
```

[image]

I have tried the following code to no avail :

```
combn(5, 2) %>% 
  t %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  mutate(
      string = paste(V1, V2, sep = ';')
    , vector = c(V1, V2)
    ) %>% View
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can have a `list` column. If we specify the `simplify = FALSE` in `combn`, it would return a `list` of vectors, which can be wrapped in `tibble` to create a `list` column

```
combn(5, 2, simplify = FALSE) %>% 
      tibble(vector = .)
```

---

Or another option is to make use of `unnest_wider` with `unite`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
combn(5, 2, simplify = FALSE) %>% 
    tibble(vector = ., vector2 = vector) %>% 
    unnest_wider(c(vector2), names_repair =
      ~ c('vector', str_c('V', 1:2))) %>% 
    unite(string, V1, V2, sep=";", remove = FALSE)
```

---

If we use the OP's method, an option is `map2` which returns a `list` after concatenate both the columns elementwise

```
library(purrr)
combn(5, 2) %>% 
  t %>% 
  as.data.frame %>% 
  mutate(
  string = paste(V1, V2, sep = ';'),
  vector =  map2(V1, V2, c))
#  V1 V2 string vector
#1   1  2    1;2   1, 2
#2   1  3    1;3   1, 3
#3   1  4    1;4   1, 4
#4   1  5    1;5   1, 5
#5   2  3    2;3   2, 3
#6   2  4    2;4   2, 4
#7   2  5    2;5   2, 5
#8   3  4    3;4   3, 4
#9   3  5    3;5   3, 5
#10  4  5    4;5   4, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in the same `combn` function by passing a function to it constructing a dataframe with all the values that you want and combine them together into one.

```
do.call(rbind, combn(5, 2, function(x) {
  df <- data.frame(V1 = x[1], V2 = x[2], string = paste(x, collapse = ";"))
  df$vector <- list(x)
  df
}, simplify = FALSE))

#   V1 V2 string vector
#1   1  2    1;2   1, 2
#2   1  3    1;3   1, 3
#3   1  4    1;4   1, 4
#4   1  5    1;5   1, 5
#5   2  3    2;3   2, 3
#6   2  4    2;4   2, 4
#7   2  5    2;5   2, 5
#8   3  4    3;4   3, 4
#9   3  5    3;5   3, 5
#10  4  5    4;5   4, 5
```